# Regex: why can't I use a capture group inside curly braces {}

Tags: bash, perl

I want to replace the nth charater of a line to '.', with n being line dependent and can be provided on the line itself, e.g. a example file can look like this:

```
$cat test
0 ABCD
1 ABCD
2 ABCD
```

The desired output is

```
0 .BCD
1 A.CD
2 AB.D
3 ABC.
```

I've tried capturing the number and using \1 inside {}, but it doesn't work:

```
$ cat test | perl -pe 's/([0-9]) ([A-Z]{\1})./\1 \2./'
0 ABCD
1 ABCD
2 ABCD
```

whereas using a normal number inside {} gives the desired output:

```
$ cat test | perl -pe 's/([0-9]) ([A-Z]{2})./\1 \2./'
0 AB.D
1 AB.D
2 AB.D
```

Using `perl` (and not `sed`) because I know that using capturing groups in the pattern does in principle work:

```
$ echo 'KALLO' | perl -pe 's/([A-Z])\1/__/'
KA__O
```

So my questions:
Why doesn't my approach with `{\1}` work?
How can I achieve what I want without using a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl expects a number after `{`, not a backslash.

You can build the pattern from variables, though, and use it in a substitution:

```
perl -pe '/^([0-9]+)/; $p = "(.* .{$1})."; s/$p/$1./'
```

Or even, on Perl 5.010+

```
perl -pe '/^([0-9]+)/; $p = ".* .{$1}\\K."; s/$p/./'
```

Comment: There is no problem with using `$1` directly in `{}` in the regex: `perl -pe '/^([0-9]+)/; s/\d+ .{$1}\K././'` works just fine. (I don't know how it's implemented exactly, but I'd guess that interpolation of `$1` is probably done before the regex is compiled)

Comment: @Dada: You're right. But `$1` cannot be used in the same pattern where it's born.

Answer (score 1):

`\1` means "match what the first capture captured". It makes no sense where you used it.

`(??{ })` could be used.

```
$ perl -ple's/^(\d)+ \s++ (??{ "." x $1 }) \K . /./sxa' test
0 .BCD
1 A.CD
2 AB.D
```

How I'd do it:

```
$ perl -ple'
   my @F = split " ", $_, 2;
   substr( $F[1], $F[0], 1 ) = ".";
   $_ = join " ", @F;
' test
0 .BCD
1 A.CD
2 AB.D
```